# Webview CapturePreviewToStreamAsync error

Tags: xaml, webview, windows-runtime

I am trying to get a screenshot of WebView in a Windows Store app with the following piece of code.

```
    IRandomAccessStream ir = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

    await scenarioDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { 
        webView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(ir).AsTask().Wait(); 
    });
```

But for some reason, I am hit with System.InvalidOperationException and message

```
"A method was called at an unexpected time."
```

The thread here is different but I verified the RunAsync callback is running on correct thread.

Edit: I tried invoking CapturePreviewToStreamAsync() directly using another button click event and it works.

```
private async void captureButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IRandomAccessStream ir = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await webView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(ir);
}
```

I also verified the thread ID in both button click event and the delegate in the RunAsync are same. Not sure what I am missing here..

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried calling the capture directly without calling it in the `RunAsync`.

Comment: From your edit, it sounds like you got it to work by using it directly. So, what is the difference between the code that works and doesn't? You'll need to include it.

Comment: No difference except the threads are different..

Comment: You can't perform a UI action like this on anything but the UI thread.

Comment: The dispatcher take care of this?

Comment: What dispatcher? Because you're using it in a Task, it's being used in a threadpool thread.